# How to combine a pagination with Observables and the AsyncPipe in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable, angular9

There's a list of products coming from an API. The products are paginated and the user can switch to another page. The simplified template looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of products$ | async">{{ product.name }}</li>
</ul>

<button type="button" (click)="gotoPage(1)">1</button>
<button type="button" (click)="gotoPage(2)">2</button>
```

The component does look like this:

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products$: Observable<Product[]>;

  constructor(
    private service: ProductService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.products$ = this.service.getAll({page: 1});
  }

  gotoPage(page: number): void {
    this.products$ = this.service.getAll({page: page});
  }
}
```

My questions are:
Is this the correct way to update the Obersavble? Or does this produce memory leaks?

<sub>As a note: The URL will not change and the component should not reloaded on pagination change.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.9/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L53-L157) of Async pipe, you can see inside `transform()` function:

```
if (obj !== this._obj) {
  this._dispose();
  return this.transform(obj as any);
}
```

Which unsubscribes previous Observable if there is one, if it is a new object. So you are safe to use it in that way.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes it clear, that it will be unsubscribed after the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even subscribe to your observable so I don't think there is possible memory leak here, you just get some datas and the async pipe handle the 'transformation' for you.

Just in case, when you subscribe to a observable, you need to add few lines of code to **properly** unsubscribe and prevent memory leak :

```
ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();
myObservable: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit(){
  this.myObservable.pipe(takeUntil(ngUnsubscribe))
  .subscribe(...)
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
  this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
}
```

A subject that will allow you to trigger the correct unsubscribe on everySubscribe that has the `takeUntil`.

The `.next` and `.complete` are necessary because `.unsubscribe` does not work as expected (Noticed it at work with NGRX and found some stackoverflow thread that talk about it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I need to subscribe in the component, what is the difference and the advantage of this over a simple: `this.subscription = this.service.getAll().subscribe()` in init and in destroy: `this.subscription.unsubscribe();`?

Comment: As I said, when using just `.unsubscribe()` have a weird behavior that sometime does not fully unsubscribe to your observables. At my job I had memory leak because it wasn't working well (cannot find the thread that gave me the answer sorry) and using this apttern solved my issue. The advantag of the `takeUntil` is that with just that it allow you to use only one subject to `next & complete` (=unsubscribe) over all of your observables.

Answer (score 0):

You can always prevent memory leaks the takeUntil + ngOnDestroy pattern.

For example,

declare a new variable `private onDestroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();`

```
this.service.getAll({page: page})
.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
.subscribe(... do the necessary ...);
```

And later, in the onDestroy() life cycle hook, you may implement the following :

```
 public ngOnDestroy(): void {
   this.onDestroy$.next();
   this.onDestroy$.complete() 
 }
```

What we have actually done is declare a new observable; Then, by using pipe method with takeUntil we inform compiler that we want to unsubscribe from the observable when any value appear in onDestroy$, Then, by using pipe method with takeUntil we inform compiler that we want to unsubscribe from the observable when any value appear in onDestroy$, thereby preventing memory leaks.

Comment: You need the `this.onDestroy$.complete()` as well to properly unsubscribe. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

As we all know with page comes also number of items per page.

I prefer to change criteria to behavior subject and combine two observables with `mergeMap`

```js
class ProductService {
  constructor() {
    this.defaultCriteria = {
      page: 0,
      pageSize: 5
    }
  }

  getAll(criteria) {
    criteria = {
      ...this.defaultCriteria,
      ...criteria
    }

    return rxjs.of(Array(criteria.pageSize).fill(0).map((pr, index) => {
      const num = index + criteria.pageSize * criteria.page + 1;
      return {
        id: num,
        name: `Product ${num}`
      }
    }))
  }

}

class ProductsComponent {
  constructor(service) {
    this.service = service;
    this.page$ = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject(0);
    this.products$ = null;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.products$ = this.page$.asObservable()
      .pipe(rxjs.operators.mergeMap(page => this.service.getAll({
        page
      })))
  }

  gotoPage(page) {
    this.page$.next(page);
  }
}

const service = new ProductService();
const component = new ProductsComponent(service);
component.ngOnInit();
component.products$.subscribe(products => console.log(products));
component.gotoPage(1);
component.gotoPage(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```